# Adding a default value along with entity in form type of Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I am a totally new in symfony2. I met a situation which I can't solve till now.
I have a controller, formtype and eventsubscriber in my project. The form builds by binding the entities. In that case for a particular entity I need to add a default value along with an ID in one of the form fields. My form type is

```
$builder->add('breed', EntityType::class, array(
      'label' => 'Breed',
      'class' => 'AppBundle:Masters\Breed',
      'placeholder' => '----Select Breed----',
      'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
          return $er->createQueryBuilder('b')
          ->orderBy('b.sortOrder', 'DESC');
      },
     'choice_label' => 'breed',
     ));
$builder->addEventSubscriber(new BreedSubscriber($factory));
```

My Event Subscriber is

```
private function addBreed($form, $breedmasterId) {
 $form->add($this->factory->createNamed('breed',EntityType::class,null, array(
  'class'         => 'AppBundle:Masters\Breed',
  'placeholder'   => '----Select Breed--------',
  'choice_label'  => 'breed',
  'required'      =>  TRUE,
  'mapped'        =>  false,
  'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $repository) use ($breedmasterId) {
         $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('bm')
                ->where('bm.breed = :breedmasterId')
                 ->setParameter('breedmasterId', $breedmasterId);
                return $qb;
                },
                'auto_initialize' => false
    )));
}
```

I need to add a default value such as "General" along with an "id" in the addBreed subscriber and it need to be validate on formsubmission. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following 'data' key in the array you configure your form:

```
$builder->add('breed',null, array(
     'label' => 'Breed',
     'data' => 'Sih Tzu'
))
```